# Flutter Firebase plugins correct versioning

Tags: plugins, flutter, version

For an app I'm developing I'm getting some crashes on some of my clients devices.
I suspect it has to do with me miss-understanding the proper way to configure all the different plugins to work together.

For instance, in this official guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup it says to use:

```
firebase_core: ^0.2.5
```

But the current plugin version (https://github.com/flutter/plugins) is:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
```

And that's only one example. There are lots of other Firebase / Firestore plugins I use, and it's really unclear on how to properly configure them.

Add to this dependencies and more configuration in the Gralde files, for example:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

Add to this the AndroidX configuration:
build.gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

So my question is:
How do I properly configure my app with all the config files (pubspec.yaml, build.gradle etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid adding libraries over `build.gradle`. You'll also need to following this steps to make sure it works with AndroidX:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Over the website you also have an specific section for non AndroidX libraries:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx

Any version above those should be safe.